# Error con permisos de Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-auth

Estoy trabajando con react y estoy tratando de obtener un documento de una colección pero cuando se ejecuta tengo el error

> Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
       auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            db.collection("policies").doc(user.uid).onSnapshot(function(doc) {
                setPolicy(doc.data())
            })
        })
```

Tengo estas reglas de seguridad en firestore:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
```

El documento se está generando con el mismo uid del usuario creado.

Agradezco mucho su apoyo.

Comment: tengo el mismo error pero con angular, viste la solucion?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

De acuerdo al mensaje de error:

> Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or
> insufficient permissions.

El problema son los permisos.

Podrías definir el acceso de esta forma sin hacer uso del userId:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
```